# Changing size of bounding box

Tags: python, vtk

Is it possible to change the size of a bounding box in VTK? If so, how can I do it? Suppose I have the following bounding box:

```
reader = vtkStructuredPointsReader()
reader.SetFileName("Hydrogen.vtk")

outline = vtkOutlineFilter()
outline.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
outlineMapper = vtkPolyDataMapper()
outlineMapper.SetInputConnection(outline.GetOutputPort())
outlineActor = vtkActor()
outlineActor.SetMapper(outlineMapper)
outlineActor.GetProperty().SetColor(0.0,0.0,1.0)
outlineActor.GetProperty().SetLineWidth(5.0)
```

I have tried looking for a property for it but I didn't find anything. Something similar to `vtkCubeAxesActor`, like the `SetBounds` method.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The vtkOutlineFilter does not have a parameter for adjusting the bounding box. You can always create a dummy polydata input to your vtkOutlineFilter whose vtkPoints object's bounds are enlarged versions of the true bounds.